# String matching from NLP input

Tags: python, nlp, string-matching, alexa-skills-kit

I am fooling around with Alexa a little. My task is to match the user input with a list of possible answers dynamically loaded from the web. In this case, it's a list of movies.

Of course I'm not able to assume there will always be a perfect match, either the user or the Echo device won't get it quite right. My current approach to overcome this is the SequenceMatcher function. So I measure the similarity of the user input and all items in the list and the winner probably is the list item the user really was talking about:

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

maxi = 0
haystack = ["Die Verurteilten", "Der Pate", "Der Pate 2", "The Dark Knight", "Die zwölf Geschworenen", "Schindlers Liste", "Pulp Fiction", "Der Herr der Ringe - Die Rückkehr des Königs", "Zwei glorreiche Halunken", "Fight Club", "Der Herr der Ringe - Die Gefährten", "Forrest Gump", "Das Imperium schlägt zurück", "Inception", "Der Herr der Ringe - Die zwei Türme", "einer flog über das Kuckucksnest", "GoodFellas - Drei Jahrzehnte in der Mafia", "Matrix", "Die sieben Samurai", "Krieg der Sterne", "City of God", "Sieben", "Das Schweigen der Lämmer", "Ist das Leben nicht schön?", "Das Leben ist schön"]
needle = "Die Gefährten"

for hay in haystack:
    ratio = SequenceMatcher(None, needle, hay).ratio()
    print('%.5f' % ratio + " " + hay)
    if ratio > maxi:
        maxi = ratio
        result = hay

print(result)
```

Most of the time I'm happy with the result. However, sometimes (and a little too often) I'm not. In case the user might ask for "Die Gefährten" like in the example above, this will happen:

```
# 0.62069 Die Verurteilten
# 0.55319 Der Herr der Ringe - Die Gefährten
# Die Verurteilten
```

For this particular case it may be an easy solution to split the list items by the separator `-`, do calculations for all resulting parts and give back the maximum score. But as the list may be anything else (recipes, books, songs, games, ...) I'm wondering if there is a more universal approach. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation for this object isn't very detailed as far as methodology, but my guess is that a Levenshtein distance method is used.

This has the the potential to fail in your use case because of the additional 'Der Herr Der Ringe' damaging the 'score' of  this method, as 'Die Verurteilten' requires fewer additions, subtraction and/or substitutions to match your query.

There are two solutions to your problem:

You can use a token matching method in which your 'score' rests heavily on individual matching words. So that 'Die Gefährten's matching both of its two words within 'Der Herr der Ringe - Die Gefährte' flag it as a 100% match. This can be combined with other, character-level methods like levenshtein and ngram character, to produce a balanced result as far as both recognizing specific token matches and potential, close token matches.

Or you can chunk your haystack aka corpus into 'chunks' n tokens long for comparison. You'll need to be able to compare the scores of these results, as you will potentially have more than match on even one listing BUT, you should be able to recognize the exact match to the 'Die Gefährte' within 'Der Herr der Ringe - Die Gefährte' as a 100% match.

You essentially need to reframe your problem from that of fuzzymatching to one of named entity recognition from unstructured text, with perhaps a little fuzzymatching to compensate for any garbledygook Alexa produces.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I think I am going for the first suggestion and do a word by word comparison, both for the user input and the original list items. Probably it will be wise to drop fill words (articles, prepositions, connectives, ...). I'll post the result as soon as I'm done.

Answer (score 1):

Based on John's input I created the following routine.

In addition to the former calculation I also do an individual word matching and calculate the average score of all words I was provided by Alexa.

The total score is the multiplication of both scores.

I also tried to ignore any fillers with presumptions based on the word length. Based on a very basic statistical summary (word count and median word length) I will ignore all words with a length of less than 5, 4 or 2 characters. Using dictionaries may be a better solution but due to the multi-language environment I would like to avoid that.

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher
from statistics import median, mean

def getWords(input):
    words = input.split()
    lengths = [ len(x) for x in words if len(x) > 1 ]

    # set the minimum word length based on word count
    # and median of word length to remove presumed fillers
    minLength = 2
    if len(words) >= 3 and median(lengths) > 4:
        minLength = 5
    elif len(words) >= 2 and median(lengths) > 3:
        minLength = 4

    # keep words of minimum length
    answer = list()
    for item in words:
        if len(item) >= minLength:
            answer.append(item) 

    return answer

matchList = ["Die Verurteilten", "Der Pate", "Der Pate 2", "The Dark Knight", "Die zwölf Geschworenen", "Schindlers Liste", "Pulp Fiction", "Der Herr der Ringe - Die Rückkehr des Königs", "Zwei glorreiche Halunken", "Fight Club", "Der Herr der Ringe - Die Gefährten", "Forrest Gump", "Das Imperium schlägt zurück", "Inception", "Der Herr der Ringe - Die zwei Türme", "Einer flog über das Kuckucksnest", "GoodFellas - Drei Jahrzehnte in der Mafia", "Matrix", "Die sieben Samurai", "Krieg der Sterne", "City of God", "Sieben", "Das Schweigen der Lämmer", "Ist das Leben nicht schön?", "Das Leben ist schön"]
userInput = "Die Gefährten"

# find the best match between the user input and the link list
maxi = 0
for matchItem in matchList:

    # ratio of the original item comparison
    fullRatio = SequenceMatcher(None, userInput, matchItem).ratio()

    # every word of the user input will be compared
    # to each word of the list item, the maximum score
    # for each user word will be kept
    wordResults = list()
    for userWord in getWords(userInput):
        maxWordRatio = 0
        for matchWord in getWords(matchItem):
            wordRatio = SequenceMatcher(None, userWord, matchWord).ratio()
            if wordRatio > maxWordRatio:
                maxWordRatio = wordRatio 
        wordResults.append(maxWordRatio)

    # the total score for each list item is the full ratio
    # multiplied by the mean of all single word scores
    itemScore = fullRatio * mean(wordResults)

    # print item result
    print('%.5f' % itemScore, matchItem)

    # keep track of maximum score
    if itemScore > maxi:
        maxi = itemScore
        result = matchItem

# award ceremony
print(result)
```

The ranked output of this routine (which is way better):

```
# 0.55319 Der Herr der Ringe - Die Gefährten
# 0.32653 Die zwölf Geschworenen
# 0.29557 Die Verurteilten
```

Extensive testing will tell how effective this solution really is.